# Deploying to Azure using VSTS repository in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a webapp in azure using VSTS as the source controls. I have this:

```
"properties": {
    "repoUrl": "https://clt-8601add0-7378-4c18-839d-8c46ac1cdd98.visualstudio.com/ResourceManagerTest/_git/[ProjectName]",
    "branch": "master",
    "isManualIntegration": true
}
```

But I get a failed provisioning state when I try this. What URL do I have to use in the template if I want to use VSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own problem. Instead of using the git url provided by the repo, use: `https://[username]:[Personal Access Token]@[url]` to authenticate with VSTS

so in my example, I might use

`https://collin:123456780abcdefg@clt-8601add0-7378-4c18-839d-8c46ac1cdd98.visualstudio.com/ResourceManagerTest/_git/[ProjectName]`

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I have to wait 1 day

Answer (score 0):

I dont think VSTS allows public repos, so you would have to authenticate to the VSTS before doing this template deployment (if this is even possible).

But since you have VSTS you are probably better off configuring a proper build\release pipeline using VSTS.

Comment: Since the VSTS account is associated with my Azure account, would the authentication be taken care of that way? We are creating a new resource group and webapp for each of our customers and want this process to be done via a tool we are creating, so that's why we're doing it with ARM templates

Comment: I dont think so, it will get taken care of by VSTS if you are using deploy to WebApp task, but not if you are using ARM Template.